# Is there a solution to this recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

Let $a(n+2) =  -a(n+1) - a(n) - 1$ for all $n\geq 1$. In this case, is there a solution for a(n) and if so, what is it and how do you find it?

Comment: It's not an equation, it's a definition. I guess you're looking for a closed form expression, not a solution.

Answer (score 2):

It depends of course on $a(0),a(1)$. Suppose $a(0)=a$ and $a(1)=b$ then

$a(2) = -a-b-1$

$a(3) = -(-a-b-1)-b-1 = a+b+1-b-1 = a$

$a(4) = -a-(-a-b-1)-1 = b$

and then the sequence repeats $a(5)$ is again $-a-b-1$.

So we have

$$a(n) = \begin{cases} \displaystyle
  a & n\text{ mod } 3 = 0\\
  b & n\text{ mod } 3 =1\\
-a-b-1 & n\text{ mod } 3 =2\\
\end{cases}$$

A formal proof is by induction on $n$.

Note that this solution makes sense because you can rewrite the equation as $a(n+2)+a(n+1)+a(n)=-1$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: It is $$a_n=c_1 \left(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i
   \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^n+c_2 \left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i
   \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^n-\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: Did we get the same solution?

Comment: @Yanko both have a period of 3, so presumably yes.